# Access Azure website by IP cause 404 error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure website that I can access by 
myname.azurewebsites.net

In Azure dashboard, the IP is 104.214.237.135

When I try to access my website by IP I have a 404 error

I don't understand. My plan App Service is S1

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure App Service is a multi-tenant service, except for App Service Environments. Apps that are not in an App Service environment (not in the Isolated tier) share network infrastructure with other apps. As a result, the inbound and outbound IP addresses of an app can be different, and can even change in certain situations.
>
> App Service Environments use dedicated network infrastructures, so apps running in an App Service environment get static, dedicated IP addresses both for inbound and outbound connections.

Azure AppService IP addresses are shared between tenants and not guaranteed to be static. Your app is bound to the hostname, not the IP address. Unless you are using App Service Environment, you cannot use a static / dedicated IP address with Azure AppServices. You can add additional custom hostnames to your app.